# Firefox and policies/preferences

Tags: linux, firefox, qubes-os

I have a small office with about 10 personnel. I want to customize Firefox for our users which I have done using policies and autoconfig.
One customization I want to do is that by default the bookmark toolbar is not shown, that is setting the browser.toolbars.bookmarks.visibility to never. I have tried to do it through policies and through autoconfig but neither works because when a new user is created then there is no profile in the users home directory. When the user first opens Firefox, the program creates the profile and puts some files into the profile folder, there among is a prefs.js file which contains the preferece to set browser.toolbars.bookmarks.visibility to always (at least that is how it is in Fedora 33) and that overwrites policies and autoconfig settings.

So I would like to know, is there a way to tell Firefox 88 to not set up the profile with a prefs.js file or to somehow make policy and autoconfig have higher priority then user preferences?

I have tried to put in the /etc/skel folder a prefs.js in /etc/skel/.mozillla/firefox/ but when the user opens Firefox for the first time then that file gets overwritten.

This is Qubes-OS and the DisposableVM that I am trying to do this on and in that setup the home directory is inherited from another VM so I don´t have control over the home directory through restarts of that VM but I want to do this for all new users, not users that have already opened the program and created the profile folder.